# How to limit the construction of an object to a couple of methods?

Tags: c++, class, private, smart-pointers

I have a `Context` class, and I would like everyone to manage it ONLY through unique_ptr(by the provided `NewInstance` static method).

So I delete the copy/ctor for the class and provide a `NewInstance` method.

```cpp
class Context
{
public:
    Context(const Context&) = delete;
    Context& operator=(const Context&) = delete;

    static std::unique_ptr<Context> NewInstance()
    {
        return std::make_unique<Context>();
    }
private:
    Context()
    {
    }
};
```

However, when I call it like

```cpp
void func()
{
    auto ctx = Context::NewInstance();
}
```

I get a compile error, saying that

```
error: ‘Context()’ is private within this context
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

I guess it's because I made `Context()` private(since I do not want other to construct it directly).

I also tried to make the `static NewInstance` a friend function to `Context`, but the error still exists.

So, what's the pattern to make a class constructable only through a couple of methods?

Comment: Duplicate explains issue, but since this is `std::unique_ptr` you can just do: `return std::unique_ptr<Context>{new Context};` without harming any optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to build a new object and create a `std::unique_ptr` from it:

```
static std::unique_ptr<Context> NewInstance()
{
    Context *ctx = new Context();
    return std::unique_ptr<Context>(ctx);
}
```